# "Слишком" как наречие образа действия

Tags: лексика, стилистика, выбор-слов

*Слишком* - это наречие разряда *образ образа*. Может ли оно характеризовать действие? Корректно ли такое предложение: *"Мы и так слишком задержались здесь"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Корректно ли такое предложение: "Мы и так слишком задержались здесь"?**

Вполне корректно. Словарь Ушакова приводит среди примеров:

> «Не нужно слишком предаваться ему (развлечению).» Гончаров.

Пример с глаголом "задержаться" можно найти в книге Ф. Купера "Зверобой":

> ...Поэтому нельзя к ней подплыть слишком быстро, нельзя там и слишком
>   задержаться.